# Apache RewriteRule ignoring RewriteCond?

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx

So I have an Apache running on OSX Server 10.4 (don't ask) with multiple sites. In `0002_[example.com].conf`, I have this bit of code:

```
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/secret/">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^137\.250\.
    RewriteRule .* /messages/secret.html
</Directory>
```

However, in this configuration, the RewriteCond always seems to evaluate to false, since the `secret` directory gets shown even if the client's address does not begin with 137.250.

If I change the config to this

```
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/secret/">
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* /messages/secret.html
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^137\.250\.
</Directory>
```

the condition either does not get evaluated at all or always evaluates to true. Either way, *all* clients get blocked.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, in this configuration, the RewriteCond always seems to evaluate to false, since the secret directory gets shown even if the client's address does not begin with 137.250.

Of course, because that's what you expressed with your `RewriteCond`! If you only want clients whose IP addresses start with `137.250.` to see the `secret.html` page you need to remove the negation (`!`) in your `RewriteCond`.

The second snippet you posted is inherently incorrect. `RewriteCond` needs to precede the `RewriteRule` it refers to.

It would be easier if you'd use `Allow`, `Deny` and a custom 403 `ErrorDocument` (see [Access Control](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html)). When using the mod_rewrite hammer, any problem begins to look like a nail... ;)

Comment: Do you have an example how to use Allow and Deny?

Comment: Also, the rule is correct: People NOT in the 137.250 range should get redirected to messages/secret.html, which tells them they can't access the secret content. The problem is that *everyone* gets redirected, even those inside the range.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html